# How to import all sql files inside folder with a single command?

Tags: centos, mysql, ssh

On a CentOS server with LAMP I have a folder with 10-20 SQL dump files. Is there a way (single line query) by which I can import all of them?

I tried the following:

1. logged in putty, navigated to to file with all SQL dump say (folder `mysqlallfile`)

   `mysqlallfile` contains: `1.sql.gz`,`2.sql.gz` and so on
2. I created sh file say `bulkimport.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   for filename in *.gz; 
   do
       tempfile="${filename##*/}"
       database_name="${tempfile%%.*}"
       echo $database_name
       mysql -pPASS -u USER -e "CREATE DATABASE $database_name"
       gzcat $filename | mysql -pPASS -uUSER $database_name
   done
   ```
3. I ran below command in the terminal:

   ```
   bash bulkimport.sh
   ```

   it returned error:

   ```
   bulkimport.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
   'ulkimport.sh: line 2: `for filename in *.gz;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You might have Windows line endings in the script file (or some other encoding error). Either save the file with Unix line endings in your editor in Windows and copy the script to the server again or use one of the myriad options to convert in Linux (e.g. `dos2unix`, `recode`, `vim`).